# Occurrence of a certain word within a text stored in columns using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm facing quiet a lot of challenges currently by doing text analysis with R.
Therefore I have in a table the columns Date, Text and Likes
I want to count how often a certain word occurs within the texts of a column (max 1 per column) and how often not.

I want to plot the results by displaying the result like in this picture

[image: python regression of trump posts]

but I would like dots for "occurrence" and "not occurrence" of the searched word with different colors as dots and aggregate it monthly on y-axis and likes on x-axis

It would be great if you could help me with this challenge

As update I have here the sample data available https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IWqDoRFBTL8er8VmvisHDeB5uM3BGgJe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions on SO (specifically or perhaps especially in the [tag:r] tag) do much better when there are specifics, such as specific sample data and code attempted. Please consider adding sample data (programmatically with `data.frame`, or the output from `dput(head(x))`), expected output given that sample data, and any code attempted so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several moving parts here so let me outline the tasks I think you are looking for assistance with:

1. Determine if a word appears in text, row by row.
2. Plot this information.
3. Display the information by category, i.e. word found or not found.
4. Provide some sort of smoothed fit over the data.

You can accomplish the first task by using your choice of pattern matching function. `grepl` for example will search with the pattern as its first argument. You may want to look into other parameters such as case sensitivity to ensure they match your needs. You'll want to store this result into another column, assuming you use `ggplot`. Then, you can pass the data to `ggplot` and use the `col` argument to have it separate out categories for you.

It doesn't appear that your data is readily available from your question. In the future, it generally helps if you can share some sample data. I have made my own sample which should be similar to what you describe. See the example code below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(5)
data <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"),
                                   to = as.Date("2021-03-01"),
                                   by = "day"),
                   fruit = sample(c("banana", "orange", "apple")),
                   likes = runif(60, 100, 1000))
data$good_fruit <- ifelse(grepl("orange", data$fruit), "orange", "not orange")
data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(Date, likes, col = good_fruit)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(Date, likes))
```

Since I threw together literally random data, there is not much a pattern here, but I think this illustrates the general idea of what you wanted to show? If you wanted a more specific kind of aggregation, I would recommend performing that manipulation before passing to ggplot, but for a rough fit this should work.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1f4H.png)

Comment: wow you saved my day it's pretty close to the result which I was seeking.
I have added also my data so this helps to identify my struggle. The only thing missing in this, is that I have a text instead of a single word and I just want to search in each row if the word for example "covid" is inside of the text or not.

Comment: You should be able to use the same solution since `grepl` matches inside a string and not just whole words. For example, you can verify that `grepl("orange", "orange")` and `grepl("orange", "This is a bowl of oranges.")` both evaluate to TRUE.